# Password Policy and Authorization Matrix

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

The main topic of this question is the Authorization Matrix in the context of SQL Server, I searched it in Google but couldn't find much result and most of what I got was not clear to understand. I wanna know what it is and how to use it.

Regarding the password policies, I found options like change pass after login, etc. Are they the actual password policy and if so how can be script it in T-SQL? is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by the Authorization Matrix. Please explain what you are trying to achieve.

Regarding scripting out password options, yes, it is possible to script them out. Either use the login window itself to script out:

[image]

Or directly use T-SQL as mentioned in this link: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161959(v=sql.120).aspx